# Subscribe to the Button's events into a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, custom-controls

Do you know how can I subscribe to an event of the base of my customControl ?
I've a custom control with some dependency properties :

```
public class MyCustomControl : Button
{
    static MyCustomControl ()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ) ) );
    }

    public ICommand KeyDownCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue( KeyDownCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( KeyDownCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyDownCommandProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register( "KeyDownCommand", typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MyCustomControl ) );

    public ICommand KeyUpCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue( KeyUpCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( KeyUpCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyUpCommandProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register( "KeyUpCommand", typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MyCustomControl ) );

    public ICommand KeyPressedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue( KeyPressedCommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( KeyPressedCommandProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyPressedCommandProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register( "KeyPressedCommand", typeof( ICommand ), typeof( MyCustomControl ) );
}
```

And I whant to subscribe to Button's events (like MouseLeftButtonDown) to run some code in my customControl.

Do you know how can I do something like this in the constructor ?

```
static MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( MyCustomControl ) ) );
        MouseLeftButtonDownEvent += (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => "something";
    }
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !

You just have to override [OnMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmouseleftbuttondown(v=VS.100).aspx) method. Don't forget to call base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown after your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that could work. If you wanted to be free of any code-behind in your xaml file and wanted to comply with MVVM, then I would have suggested you look into Attached Behaviors.

Here is a link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx

It's a very good resource and saved me just last week.